# accessing the header of parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to access the parent windows header and trying to append it to a `new` `window` with a `div` content to `print`.

```
var headerPart = $("head").html();
var contentPart = $("#div").html();
var newWindow= window.open("", "w");
newWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(headerPart);
$(newWindow.document.body).html(contentPart);
newWindow.focus();
newWindow.print();
newWindow.close();
```

I am just getting a blank new `window`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the point you are missing :

```
window.open("", "w");
```

will open a blank window.

```
window.opener;
```

will give you a reference to the opener (parent) window